# Angular 4 RouteModule.forRoot(ROUTES) not loading routes in order to get lazy loading working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to convert an existing project to use lazy loading, but I cannot get any routes loaded in the app.module.

app.module.ts:

```js
...

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AppService,
        OCodeService,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AppHeaderComponent,
        FreeTrialModalComponent,
        TopBarReminderComponent,
        ForgotPasswordComponent

    ],
    imports: [
        FirebaseModule,
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([{ path: 'create', component: AppHeaderComponent }], {enableTracing: true}),
        SharedModule,
        AuthModule,
        FormsModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        SlimLoadingBarModule.forRoot(),
        ToastyModule.forRoot(),
        SwiperModule.forRoot(SWIPER_CONFIG),
        HttpModule,

        //VIEWS
        AccountModule,
        NotificationsModule,
        LandingModule,
        HomeModule,
        //CreateModule,
        ManageModule,
        EventModule,
        SearchModule,
        //MarketingModule,
        FollowingModule,
        BookmarkModule,

        EmailActionModule,
        LoginModule,

        ProfileModule
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        SignInComponent,
        JoinComponent,
        FreeTrialModalComponent,
        ForgotPasswordComponent,
        SignInComponent,
        JoinComponent,
        NeedOcodeComponent,
    ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

I get no errors when doing this and the route is not recognized and sent to the ** catch all route.

All of the imported modules have .forChild(ROUTES) and work correctly, it's just the forRoot(ROUTES) on the app.module.ts that are not working correctly.

I am using angular-cli

Here is my package.json (there may be some remnants from using webpack before):

```js
{
  "name": "oevent2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.25",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.64",
    "@types/request": "^0.0.30",
    "@types/request-promise": "^3.0.32",
    "angular2-bootstrap-pagination": "^2.1.2",
    "angular2-clipboard": "^2.0.14",
    "angular2-modal": "^2.0.2",
    "angular2-polyfill": "0.0.32",
    "angular2-tag-input": "^1.1.2",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^1.0.1",
    "angular2-toaster": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-ui-switch": "^1.2.0",
    "angularfire2": "*",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.3",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.6.4",
    "chart.js": "^2.3.0",
    "core-js": "~2.4.1",
    "dragula": "^3.7.2",
    "elasticsearch": "^13.3.1",
    "firebase": "^3.9.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^3.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "install": "^0.8.4",
    "json-2-csv": "^2.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "momentjs": "^2.0.0",
    "mtr-datepicker": "^0.3.5",
    "mydatepicker": "^1.1.3",
    "mydaterangepicker": "^1.0.14",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.4.0",
    "ng2-datepicker": "^1.4.6",
    "ng2-datetime": "^1.2.2",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.2.1",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "^0.8.8",
    "ng2-inline-editor": "^0.1.1-alpha.3",
    "ng2-meta": "^2.0.3",
    "ng2-page-slider": "^0.8.0",
    "ng2-pagination": "^2.0.0",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^2.0.5",
    "ng2-social-share": "0.0.10",
    "ng2-summernote": "^1.11.0",
    "ng2-toasty": "*",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-ui-switch": "^1.3.9",
    "npm": "^4.1.1",
    "papaparse": "^4.3.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.0",
    "social-share-ng2": "^0.2.4",
    "summernote": "^0.8.2",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3",
    "@types/core-js": "~0.9.30",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "autoprefixer": "~6.4.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.9",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cross-env": "~2.0.0",
    "css-loader": "~0.23.1",
    "del-cli": "~0.2.0",
    "eslint": "~3.3.0",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "~2.22.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "~0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "~1.8.0",
    "minx": "r-park/minx.git",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "node-sass": "~3.8.0",
    "nodemon": "~1.10.0",
    "npm-run-all": "~2.3.0",
    "postcss-loader": "~0.9.1",
    "raw-loader": "~0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "~4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "~0.13.1",
    "ts-helpers": "~1.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "~0.8.2",
    "typings": "~1.3.2",
    "winston": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Here is where I have my catch all route in /src/app/profile/profile.module.ts:

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ProfileComponent } from "./components/profile-component";
import {ProfileService} from "./services/profile-service";
import {CatchRoutesComponent} from "./components/catch-routes-component";
import {FollowingModule} from "../following/following.module";
import {SharedModule} from "../shared-module/shared.module";
import {AuthGuard} from "../auth/guards/auth-guard";

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    {path: '**', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ProfileComponent,
        CatchRoutesComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
        FollowingModule,
        SharedModule
    ],
    providers: [
        ProfileService
    ]



})

export class ProfileModule {}

export { };
```

Here is the trace from the routes:

[image]

Comment: There is only one `create` route shown in your configuration. I don't see any lazy loading going on here?

Comment: I just can't get the .forRoot() to load anything, let a lone try to hit the create module and lazy load it

Comment: so I'm just trying to load a component at least and have it recognize the route.  Right now if I go to /create it just send me to the ** catch all route

Comment: Where is the ** catch all route defined? I don't see it here?

Comment: Once I can get it to recognize a route I'll try lazy loading.

Comment: It's in the ProfileModule

Comment: So if you enter in the address bar something like this: `http://localhost:4200/create`, you get no errors and it falls through to the wild card route? Since I see you have route events turned on, could you post what your route events look like when you enter the above route?

Comment: I added information on the ProfileModule which has the catch-all route in it and is directly imported into app.module.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153802/discussion-between-shane-loveland-and-deborahk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as long as I can understand, you are trying to convert your eagerly loaded modules to lazily loaded modules:

**step 1:**
remove the modules from the root module imports array

```
imports: [
    FirebaseModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([{ path: 'create', component: AppHeaderComponent }], {enableTracing: true}),
    SharedModule,
    AuthModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    SlimLoadingBarModule.forRoot(),
    ToastyModule.forRoot(),
    SwiperModule.forRoot(SWIPER_CONFIG),
    HttpModule,
```

**step 2:** configure your root routing so each lazy module gets loaded when a certain route is activated here is a few examples:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {PageNotFoundComponent} from './404/page-not-found.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'account', loadChildren: './modules/account/account.module#AccountModule'},
  {path: 'login', loadChildren: './modules/login/login.module#LoginModule'},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

**step 3:** don't forget to configure each module routing

Comment: I'm still not quite sure why the .forRoot() wouldn't load the way I had it in my question (mixed with child routes that were eager).  Moving all the routing to app.module.ts made it work though.

Comment: This helped me out. In my main routing file I had a left over module import for the module I was lazy loading.